# There exists water. is "there" a dummy subject?

Tags: sentence-structure

"There exists water"

Is "there" a dummy subject or is it just inversion and is "water" a grammatical subject?

Comment: Is water a subject?? If you remove there, you would have to rewrite: Water exists [in some place]. ""there exists" is very awkward here. There exists water is *not* Water exists there.

Comment: @Lambie The example was just a simple one to serve as a basis for discussion. *There exist very few photos of the reclusive writer.*

Comment: @Lambie Then, "there" is a grammatical subject in "there exists water"?

Comment: @Collins.   Your sentence is not something a native speaker is ever likely to say.  *There exists water on planet X3452* , yes, but not "There exists water".

Comment: I'm not sure it's fair to pose grammatical questions about a non-idiomatic and confusing sentence. "Water exists there" makes sense if we already have a frame of reference for "there," like "on Mars." "Water exists" makes... well, some sense, aside from being such an obvious observation as to be confusing.

Comment: "There exists..." is a set phrase in the jargon of formal logic, but it is almost never used in everyday speech. I will sometimes humorously use it (especially in the sentence "There exists a solution"), but only when I'm deliberately trying to sound like an overly-logical but impractical pure scientist.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Yes, and who is using formal logic?

Comment: @Lambie - No one, but it might explain why OP might have encountered that phrase. They should know that it's jargon within that field, but not colloquial in everyday English.

Comment: I've downvoted this question. It's not useful as it is not something anyone is ever likely to say to express this idea.  The natural expression is "Water exists." - But that is so obvious that again almost nobody would actually say it.  You would use the simple verb  "is" to say "There is water on the floor". But your example is not useful

Comment: Questions that ask about the grammar and/or meaning of an unnatural, artificial utterance which no native speaker would ever say, don't belong on ELL.

Comment: Perhaps a better example would be *"**There is a God**!"* That will have been said far more often than *"**There exists water**"*, but it looks like the same syntactic issue to me.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, *there* is a dummy subject here. We know this because it inverts with the auxiliary verb, whether it's *be* or (more rarely) *do*:

(1) *There is some water in the desert, isn't there?*

(2) *There has to be some water, doesn't there?*

In other cases, sentence-initial *there* may just be a preposed adjunct.

(3) *There he stood before me, his wicked heathen eyes locked on mine.*

The subject here is *he*, not *there*: notice there's no possibility to construct a question tag with *there* in this sentence.

Comment: Are we saying that "There exists water, doesn't there?" is well-formed? It seems marginal at best.

Comment: @JamesK "There exists water" is not idiomatic in itself, with or without the tag (although I don't think it's ungrammatical). That's why I used different examples to illustrate the larger point about the same grammatical construction.

Comment: @JamesK: There are dozens of written instances of [There is a God, isn't there?](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22There+is+a+God+isn%27t+there%22) in Google Books, and that looks like the same construction to me.

Comment: The wording was "There exists water" not "There is a god".  The answer should first address the actual question. "There is" is an idiom, "There exists" is not.

Comment: @JamesK Yep, but Fumble Fingers likes to slither the toves. Ha ha.

Answer (score 0):

**There as a dummy subject**

> There operates as a dummy subject in the construction there is or
> there are. There is/are indicates that something or someone **exists** or
> is in a particular place or situation:
>
> There’s a woman waiting outside who wants to talk to you. (The real
> subject is the woman – she is waiting outside.).
>
> Not: Is a woman waiting outside … or It’s a woman waiting outside…
>
> There are two shops in the village.
>
> Not: Are two shops … or They are two shops…

[Cambridge Grammar](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/dummy-subjects)

Notice: it means **there exists** but are/is is better.

*There exists water. is not semantically meaningful.*

Water does or does not exist on the moon. is semantically meaningful.